# Why does fetch look wobbly on React Native Android?

Tags: network-programming, react-native

I'm having a very weird problem with fetch on React Native.

I don't know if it's a question for here but I'm trying anyway!

I'm using FETCH to fetch data from my API. Each time a FETCH is run, I run a setTimeout which allows to abort() the current fetch after 30 seconds if there is still no answer.
On iOS, everything works perfectly, however, on Android, I regularly have fetch timeouts.
As if the fetch crashes from time to time?

I really don't understand where it can come from, maybe there are ports to open on the native android side? Or does Android have a different network management compared to iOS that I should know about in order to better manage the connection?

Could using Axios instead of fetch solve this problem?

Edit: My API is in https and I also added the line 'android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"' to be sure it couldn't come from there, but the fetch is still wobbly.

I hope I made myself clear!

Thank you for that, 
Viktor

Comment: Seems that axios is worth a try. I know that axios is better than fetch at reporting errors, perhaps this will help.

Comment: Hey actually, I'd already heard it was worth it! But generally speaking, I don't understand why my Android application seems to have a lot of trouble to connect to my API while on iOS, no problem !

Comment: Neither do I...

Comment: I have published a new question that I think may have something to do with this problem, if you have the answer, don't hesitate to answer it ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247555/what-happens-when-i-execute-several-fetch-at-the-same-time